# column should be converted into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

have the following table with data

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_shirt_sizes](
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
   [Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [Length] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [Chest] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [Shoulder] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [Sleeve Length] [varchar](100) NULL
  )
insert into T_shirt_sizes values('XXS','20’','29”','13 1/4”','6”')
insert into T_shirt_sizes values('XS','21 3/4”','31"','14 1/2”','6 1/8”')
insert into T_shirt_sizes values('S','23 3/4”','33"','16 1/4”','6 1/4')
insert into T_shirt_sizes values('M','25 3/4”','36"','17','7”')
insert into T_shirt_sizes values('L','27 3/4”','39"','17 1/2”','7 1/2')
```

I want to get output like this

```
 T-shirts   | XXXS    | XXS    | XS     |   S       |  M    | L
 -----------------------------------------------------
 Length      18 3/4”  | 20’    |21 3/4” | 23 3/4”   |25 3/4”|   27 3/4”
 Chest          27”   | 29”    |31”     |  33”      |  36”  |    39”
 Shoulder     12 1/2” | 13 1/4”| 14 1/2”| 16 1/4”   |17”    |  17 1/2”
 Sleeve Length  5 1/2”| 6”     | 6 1/8” |  6 1/4    |7”     |  7 1/2
```

Please help to solve the above issue

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Tell us what you have done, write the code, and if you're having problem with it then ask a specific question.

Comment: Your input data does not contain `XXXS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` again:

```
WITH Unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT Code, Fields, [Value]
    FROM #T_shirt_sizes
    UNPIVOT( [Value]
             FOR Fields IN( [Length],[Chest],[Shoulder],[Sleeve Length])) AS u
)
SELECT Fields AS [T-Shirt], [XXXS], [XXS], [XS], [S], [M],[L]
FROM Unpivoted
PIVOT ( MAX([Value])
        FOR Code IN([XXXS], [XXS], [XS], [S], [M],[L])) AS piv;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/390797)**</kbd>